# Export WSDLs form wso2 greg-4.6.0

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I want to know how to export more than one wsdls in same time in wso2 greg-4.6.0.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by exporting?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan I want to download 40 wsdls in same time.(not one by one)

Answer (score 1):

you could try to write a bash script that invoke the "ant download" from $GREGHOME/samples/filesampleutils/src

you should check [export import registry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Exporting+and+Importing+a+File+to+Remote+Registry)

Regards
Claudio